# Setup authentication for instance mongoDB - DOCKER

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have an instance of mongoDB when I execute `docker-compose up -d` the `mongoDB` container is run and he attempt to take the authentification from user.

But I use a docker-compose and I set the credentials inside of this, but when running `docker-compose up` the user are not connected.

Below, you can see my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: kolacaine/docker-hello-world
    ports:
    - "80:8081"
    depends_on:
    - mongo-service
  mongo-service:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: myUserAdmin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
    command: mongod --auth
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

And nothing happens, he always ask authentification inside of my container.

Comment: "he always ask authentification inside of my container." "he" is referred to the web container?

Comment: Nope, for `mongo-service` when I running the shell of mongodb he always ask me to connect, but I set the credentials into my docker-compose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and password, they are used to **create** a default root user not to provide pre-filled credential. Thus to connect to the mongo shell you need to use `mongo -u myUserAdmin -p abc123`.

PS `command: mongod --auth` is redundant, the entrypoint script does it automatically when it sees you using these 2 envs.

Comment: Ok alright, but when I do not have the `2 envs` the API works correctly, but If detect he have the `2 envs` the API don't works. 
Why ?

Comment: @KolaCaine: because you don't specify any auth information in the client

Comment: Because now it needs a password to connect to mongo

Comment: When I use HTTP request or something else for calling my API, I always need to precise the username and password ?

Comment: @KolaCaine yes that's the point of setting a password, a connection string like `mongodb://usr:pwd@mongodb:27017/testdb`

Comment: Oh yes ! I'm a terrible idiot... It's right thanks a lot !